# How to print <x> lines before and <y> lines after <z>th line

Tags: text-processing

The question asked **[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261263/print-some-lines-before-and-after-pattern-match-excluding-lines-matching-another)** asks for some lines before and afer pattern match.

But here objective is to take a line number and to fetch some lines before and after it from a file

EG:

```
seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If line number is 6 it should provide 4 numbers before, that line, and 3 numbers after that line. That is

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: `printf %s\\n {1..20} | sed -n 5,15p`

Comment: This will produce range of lines from n to n. This is not what I asked for. Please read edited question with example.

Comment: Well, you're about to find out that sometimes it's easier to do simple arithmetic yourself than write a _script_ to do it. _shrug_

Comment: `If line number is 6` What decide it is line 6? Do you search for a word or something? This line `seq 10 | grep -B4 -A3 "6"` will search for a line which matches `"6"` and print 4 lines before and 3 lines after.

Comment: It was mere example to represent the problem. Thats why I mentioned that the solution should not rely on pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z=6   # focus line
x=4   # lines before
y=3   # lines after

start=$(( z - x ))
end=$(( z + y ))
```

Using `sed`:

```
seq 10 | sed -n "$start,${end}p"
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

This simply uses the print (`p`) command of `sed` with a explicit range of lines to print. The other lines are ignored using `-n`.

Using `awk`:

```
seq 10 | awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" 'NR >= start { print } NR >= end { exit }'
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

This is similar to Stéphane Chazelas' answer, but implemented in `awk`; the script starts outputting the input lines after having read `start` number of lines. At `end` number of lines, the script exits.

Both alternatives will display a portion of the input data, starting at `x` lines before the line `z` and ending `y` lines after line `z`.

Comment: Simpler `awk`: `seq 10 | awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" 'NR==start,NR==end'`

Comment: For the sed solution in case of big files you need to apply an exit condition , otherwise `sed` will exit when the whole file is over - see my benchmark.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I know. That is basically Stéphane's answer though, so I don't feel I can use it...

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: By the way, in my little benchmark awk needed three times more time than sed!

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I'm not entirely surprised. `awk` is a high-level language while `sed` is a stream editor. `awk` has more to think about, so to speak, field splitting etc.

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX shells:

```
$ before=4 after=3 line=6
$ seq 10 | sed "$((line-before)),\$!d; $((line+after))q"
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Translates to:

- **d**elete any line but (`!`) from the range from the *line - before*<sup>th</sup> one to the end (`$`).
- **q**uit on the *line + after*<sup>th</sup> line

That way we don't even bother reading past the *line + after*<sup>th</sup> line.

That means however that the command feeding its data to `sed` will get aborted with a SIGPIPE if it continues sending data shortly after that which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness :

```
$ l=60;seq 100 |head -n$((l+3)) |tail -n+$((l-4))
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
```

Rumors and various benchmarks say that the combination of head + tail is much faster than any other tool:

```
$ a=1000000000
$ time seq $a |awk 'NR>=499998{print}NR >= 500004 { exit }' 
499998
499999
500000
500001
500002
500003

real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.152s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time seq $a |sed -n "499998,500003p"
499998
499999
500000
500001
500002
500003

real    1m30.249s
user    1m21.284s
sys 0m12.312s

$ time seq $a |sed "$((500000-2)),\$!d; $((500000+3))q"  #Stephan's Solution
499998
499999
500000
500001
500002
500003

real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.044s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time seq $a |head -n$((500000+3)) |tail -n+$((500000-2))
499998
499999
500000
500001
500002
500003

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time seq $a |sed -n "499998,500003p;500004q"
499998
499999
500000
500001
500002
500003

real    0m0.056s
user    0m0.048s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# define line range constants
before=4
  line=6
 after=3

# setup the sed commands s.t. pattern space holds $before number
# of lines before we hit the line number $line and $after after
s='$!N'
p=`seq -s "$s"   "$before"`
a=`seq -s "$s" 0 "$after"`

N=${p//[0-9]/;}
n=${a//[0-9]/;}

# main...
seq 10 |
sed -e "
   1{ $N }
   \$d;N
   $line!D
   $n;q
"
```

Another method is slurping the file and set the `FS` to `\n` so that the fields (now lines) are in `@F`. What remains is slicing it around the 6th
line and 4elements before and 3 lines after:

```
perl -alF\\n -0777ne '$,=$\;print @F[6-4-1..6+3-1]' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```