# Print output matching pattern till other pattern match

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, python

I am trying to print text after a pattern match till it matches other pattern several times in a file. I have tried to modify the script given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261263/print-some-lines-before-and-after-pattern-match-excluding-lines-matching-another) but failed to do it. 
eg.
The content of `file1.txt`

```
example text
more example
pattern1
important text
very important 
need this too
pattern2
i dont require this
junk text
more junk
pattern1
important text
very important 
need this too
pattern2
junk
```

Expected Output

```
pattern1
important text
very important 
need this too
pattern1
important text
very important 
need this too
```

can anyone suggest the edit?

Thanks.

Comment: Im absolutely sure this has a duplicate, but can't find it with a cursory search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching between lines between patterns, including either boundary, is a standard range selector in sed:

```
sed -n -e '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' example.txt
```

Depending on how efficiency-critical you are (how big the files are), I'd probably be lazy and use a second pass to delete the pattern2 markers:

```
cat example.txt \
| sed -n -e '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' \
| sed    -e '/pattern2/d'
```

(Yes, this is a useless use of cat, because I prefer the readability of chaining several piping filters over the performance loss, and I'm not sure right now if `< example.txt | sed ... | sed ...` is mandated by POSIX or just an extension that happens to be present in bash and zsh.)

Comment: Also, `sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{/pattern2/d;p;}' file`.